# Cast mock objects to their abstract base class in C++

Tags: c++, unit-testing, constructor, mocking, abstract-class

I have a class looking somewhat like this:

```
class TheClassIWantToTest {
public:
    TheClassIWantToTest(const IInput& input) {
        setLocalParameter(input.getParameter());
    }
    // other stuff, e.g. setLocalParameter, defined below
}
```

where the input argument is defined as

```
class IInput {
    virtual double getParameter() const = 0;
}
```

I also have an implementation of `IInput` which I use in my system, and a mock implementation created with Google Mocks.

Now, I want to be able to do something like

```
MockInput mock; // MockInput : IInput
TheClassIWantToTest sut(mock);
```

in my tests, while doing

```
RealInput theRealStuff; // RealInput : IInput
TheClassIWantToTest(theRealStuff);
```

but when I try to compile, I get errors about no method `TheClassIWantToTest(MockInput)` being defined. I tried to define a copy-constructor for `IInput` that takes a `MockInput`, but then I get `error: definition of implicitly-declared IInput(const MockInput&)` since I haven't defined the method in my class declaration.

However, I'd rather avoid declaring the copy constructor in the base class definition, since that would mean defining test methods in my production code. (I realize I could solve this by just taking a `IInput*` pointer instead, but if possible I'd like to avoid this too.)

I can't imagine I'm the first to try to accomplish this, but I haven't been able to find out how to do it. Is there a way? If so, how do you do it?

Answer (score 1):

Try the dynamical cast:

```
RealInput theRealStuff; // RealInput : IInput
TheClassIWantToTest(dynamic_cast<const IInput&>(theRealStuff));
```

Comment: Sigh... turns out what I was trying to do was really possible in the first place. However, for some stupid reasons the names of my actual classes in this specific case did not conform to the naming conventions - your tip helped me find out why it didn't work, but `TheClassIWantToTest(theRealStuff)` actually works just fine. What turned out to be the problem was that I had three classes; `B : A` and `C : A`, and tried to convert `B` to `C` rather than to `A`, because `B` had a name that made me think it was `A`...

Comment: To clarify: the problem was that the constructor was defined as `TheClassIWantToTest(const RealInput& input)` rather than what I specified in the question. Changing that to `IInput` everything I tried initially "just works"(TM).